What is DuetExpertCentre?
I have noticed my ARQ back-up sometimes fails to back up some files in /Users/{myUserId}/Library/DuetExpertCentre. I see errors such as this:
Error: /Users/mike/Library/DuetExpertCenter/_ATXAppLaunchLocation: Failed to open file: Operation not permitted

I have tried searching on Google for information about DuetExpertCentre in macOS. The results tend to point to "Duet", which looks like a screen-sharing app for macOS. I don't have that app installed.
What is DuetExpertCentre and should I be concerned that some files in that folder cannot be backed up?

It's not documented, but likely related to CoreDuet and other private frameworks that handle Continuity synchronization between Apple devices. The folder causing errors is restricted by TCC. Since the contents are auto-generated, you can safely exclude them from backups. See:
Controlling app access to files in macOS (support.apple.com)

Thanks for that. Your CoreDuet suggestion fits with my usage and observations about when the files fail to back up.
